# Setting the installation location for simple mode

Tags: eclipse, oomph

Creating an Oomph setup file for Eclipse installation.

Setting the variable `installation.location` works when using advanced mode in Oomph to complete the installation, it doesn't even allow the location to be specified (which is how I want it to work) However, when using simple modeit still prompts the user to specify the location, and the default value isn't even the path that I set in `installation.location`.

How do I set the install location for simple mode?